# Can we have conditional CSS styling?

Tags: functions, css

Can we apply css based on post category. For example I have below css

```
.question-content-text{font-size: 16px;}
```

This is applicable to all posts, my requirement is to have different css based on post category as follows

```
If (post_category_id = 1 ) then this css .question-content-text{font-size: 16px;} 
If (post_category_id = 2 ) then this css .question-content-text{font-size: 25px;}
IF (post_category_id not in (1, 2)  ) then this css .question-content-text{font-size: 50px;}
```

If its possible, Could you please help me to get this within my child theme

Comment: This totally depends on your theme. For example the Twenty Twenty theme has the category-<your-category> class added.

Comment: thanks @Tobias but can we achieve this if the theme doesn't have this already?

Comment: What's your theme?

Comment: hi @Tobias its discy theme.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Discy theme also has the category in the classes like shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Simply add your styles to the class.

Example:

```
.question-category-language {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.question-category-analytics {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tobias but it is not working as expected. Font-size property is not working and just to test if i use code '.question-category-logical-puzzles {background : #008888;}', it is applicable to entire page (within that category). My requirement is to refer section .question-content-text  my website is https://askpuzzle.com